# How to parse an XML AJAX Response

Tags: javascript, php, xml, laravel-5.5

**Image**
[image]
**Scenario**

Im using ajax to post data to my backend and buy a domain, i'm getting a response but the response is in xml. I can simply access the child nodes by using: `let Registered = data.object.CommandResponse.DomainCreateResult;` but the DomainCreateResult node has attributes on it. if you look at the image above you'll see that to access them I need to access @attribute, but this throws an error because of the @ symbol.

I've read around the internet for what to do and it seems that everyone is parsing XML documents, but I don't think this is the same as parsing a document. I'm new to messing around with XML in PHP and Javascript.

How do i access the @attributes from this XML response? Thank you for all the help in advance.

Comment: Have you tried `data.object.CommandResponse.DomainCreateResult[ '@attributes' ]` ?  ELse you can parse the xml into an xml document, you can use the basic `getElementById()` method and its variations to select elements just as you do with html. Personally, I just don't bother and aprse the xml into json before coding any logic. There's multiple different tools to do so. And worst case, if the xml is simple enough, you can split the text using basic string methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [] notation

```
let Registered = data.object.CommandResponse.DomainCreateResult['@attributes'].Domain;
```

Comment: Thank you! this works completely i wasnt aware i could do this